# C prompt ordering for reading string with getchar()

Tags: c

This is a newbie question. I am new to C programming. I have the following code which does not prompt for 'Name' Onece the 'Age' is entered, it bypass the 'Name section.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[30],ch;
    int age;

    printf("Enter age : ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    int i=0;
    printf("Enter name: ");

    while((ch = getchar())!='\n')
    {
        name[i]=ch;
        i++;
    }
    name[i]='\0';

    printf("Name: %s\n",name);
    printf("Age : %d\n", age);
    return 0;
}
```

After reading first prompt it bypass the second prompt which is using getchar() function. But if I change the order of prompt to ask for 'Name' first and then 'Age' it works fine.

The working code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[30],ch;
    int age;

    int i=0;
    printf("Enter name: ");

    while((ch = getchar())!='\n')
    {
        name[i]=ch;
        i++;
    }
    name[i]='\0';

    printf("Enter age : ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    printf("Name: %s\n",name);
    printf("Age : %d\n", age);
    return 0;
}
```

My coding IDE is CodeBlock and my compiler is GNU C Compiler (mingw32-gcc.exe)

Please help me to breakthrough.

Comment: From memory, `scanf("%d ")` (with a space) will read whitespace (including the \n on input)

Comment: Dear all, may be it is duplicate, I am newbie in c. I am confused in this. Thats y i opened a new question. try to help me understand please.

Comment: bhai just add a getchar() above the while loop, which will take the extra '\n'

Comment: @BlueBird If you have a look at the answers on duplicates, you will understand it. Also, documentation. (And don't use `scanf()`, it's insane, evil and counter-intuitive. Use `fgets()` instead.)

Comment: Yes, I used fgets() function. It seems works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few improvements/advices to the code in the question:

1. the type of the return value of `getchar()` is `int`, so the type of `ch` also should be `int`
2. you could (and should, I believe) use format `%s` to read the `name`, this is easier and the leading white spaces in the input stream would not be a problem
3. the user of the code could give a name which contains more than 30 characters, and this input could crash your program, so you should protect your code for this possibility. You have two options:

   a. use format '%29s" to read the `name`
   b. change the definition of `name` to `char *name`, read it by `scanf("%ms", &name);`, and call `free(name);` after you do not need it anymore

Here is an example, in which the name can be very long and can include spaces:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *name;
    int age;

    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%m[^\n]", &name);

    printf("Enter age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);

    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
    printf("Age : %d\n", age);

    free(name);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And here is a run of it:

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter name: a very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong name
Enter age: 12
Name: a very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong name
Age : 12
```

Comment: hi leeduhem, thanks for your explanation. I tried using scanf() but it breaks once there is a space. Any way, I can see an aditional m in your code scanf("%ms", &name) . Actually what is that mean by "%ms" ? it will read along with the space?

Comment: @BlueBird  The `m` modifier is a POSIX.1-2008 extension to C89/C99, which means `scanf()` itself will allocate (through `malloc()`) the needed space to store the input string, and the caller is responsible to free this space by `free()`. You can check out [scanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) and `scanf(3)` for future details.

Comment: @BlueBird To read everything except newline in a line, you can you using the format `%m[^\n]`. I will add a example in my above answer.

Answer (score 1):

In first code the `\n` character left behind by the `scanf` is read by `getchar`. This makes the condition `(ch = getchar())!='\n'` in `while` loop `false` and the loop body never get executed.
You need to consume that `\n` character which comes up to the buffer along with the `age` you entered on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
Putting the statement

```
while(getchar()!='\n');
```

after the `scanf` will consume all of the newline characters.

Your second code is working fine because `%d` skips white-space characters unlike `%c` specifiers.

Comment: what if I added another getchar(); to read the '\n' before go to while loop?

Comment: It will work only for one `\n`. Suppose if a user pressed Enter key more than once then it will not work.